# theme-color modification through CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change `<meta name="theme-color" content="#xxxxxx">` through a CSS file? For example, I got 8 different themes for the generic style I got (just some color changes etc), I want it to change the theme-color with the stylechange as well.

Using JS should do the trick as well, but I just want to know that is it possible to do it through CSS as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this cannot be done using only CSS.

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering. I'll work around it with JavaScript then! Cheers!